# using column alias in where clause MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, column-alias

I have two queries run on mysql. The first one returns an error while the seconds one returns an empty set and no error happens.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',' , firstName, lastName) `Full Name` 
FROM employees 
WHERE `Full Name` LIKE '%on';
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Full Name' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',' , firstName, lastName) 'Full Name' 
FROM employees
WHERE 'Full Name' LIKE '%on';
```

> Empty set (0.00 sec)

Another odd thing about the second query is that it **should** return some rows ( notice `Patterson`)!

[image]

Can someone help me explain the difference between these two queries and why the second one doesn't return the correct result?

Answer (score 2):

In your second query, you're essentially comparing the string "Full Name" to `%on` which always evaluates to `false`, and will therefore will never return results. Further, if you were to alter that to `'Full Name' like '%me'`, you'd get all of the records back because that expression always evaluates to `true`.

I've seen it said that it's not possible to use aliases in `where` clauses, but I think that may be inaccurate. Here, the backtick (`) character is acting like a delimiter for table, column, and field names whereas the apostrophe (') is not; that denotes strings and other values. Assuming that's true, you should be able to drop the backticks if you change the alias to something like `full_name`.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you are not setting your `AS` (Firstname,Lastname) as a variable and therefore it cannot be used in your `WHERE`.  You are LITERALLY comparing "Firstname, Lastname" to `%on%`  -- Since you are using spaces in the `AS` instead of an underscore or camelCase, the ticks will not do what you want, and therefore the need for a single or even double quote .. `'` OR `"` will suffice if there is a space in the `AS`

Also no need for `CONCAT_WS` if you are only combining 2 fields

To get your WHERE clause to compare to actual results, you also have to `conacat` --

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstName, ',' , lastName) AS 'Full Name' 
FROM employees
WHERE CONCAT(firstName, ',' , lastName) LIKE '%on';
```